# What is the least buggy time of year to travel to Michigan's Upper Penninsula?

Tags: bugs

I have been to the upper peninsula a number of times and some trips have been amazing, but some have been so swarmed with biting flies or smaller swarms of black flies that it was difficult to enjoy anything. I don't want to go in winter.

Outside of winter, when is the least buggy time to visit? Are there predictable times when the more annoying insects tend to spawn?

Comment: No experience on the UP, but other places I've been one opts for either black fly season (early) or mosquito season. I'll take mosquitos over black flies any day.  If there aren't horses around I've found the number of biting flies goes down a lot.

Comment: For the Adirondacks, I remember people saying that the no-go black fly season was from Mother's Day to Father's Day, i.e. early May to mid-June.  Not sure if that is backed by any data, or if it would apply to Michigan.

Comment: > Outside of winter Unfortunately, that's your answer. Just accept the situation.

Comment: In my experience over various territories fly and mosquito seasons vary wildly based on the short term weather and temperature. As such there can be certain months or years where there are almost none of the critters, while at other times it can be unbearable. At least in Scandinavia this was very hard to predict ahead of time, and your best bet  is to get some information from locals about what the _current_ situation is, and then decide based upon that.

Answer (score 2):

Tldr: best avoid hiking in the UP mid may until august.

Based on personal experience there are two main bugs to avoid in the UP. The black flies and the mosquitos. Black flies are the worse of the two as they will bite you through thick layers.

Both bugs require standing water to hatch, and have a few days before they can fly. Avoiding wet and warm months is better for this reason. After august high humidity days that both enjoy are few and far between. After large rainstorms are the worst.

This post asking a similar question gives about the same advice.

https://backpackinglight.com/forums/topic/75841/